# Firebase Realtime Database large data set

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a little over 100,000 data locations, each location is stored in firebase's database as a dictionary with a latitude, longitude, name, and url to an image as string. The data takes about 4-5mins to load from the server. All the data needs to load because it is map data and the user may be viewing zoomed all the way out. I saw a little performance increase by separating the data points into separate children in groups of 1,000 and then load each 1,000 individually but it is still very slow. Any thoughts on how load the data quicker would be super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider loading the data and storing it locally when the user opens the app?

Comment: Loading 100K items into a mobile app is never a good idea, think of the bandwidth you're consuming. You're not going to show 100K items on a single screen, so you shouldn't load them. If the user is zoomed out, you'll show clusters of those items. So it's best to store clusters of items for that map view.

Comment: Thanks for responding Frank.... Yea, that was my thought (using clustering). I need to show all the data points.